# 2nd level cache off, still get Cache item expired while locked?

Tags: asp.net, nhibernate, caching, iis

We have a web application where we notice a lot of problem with the following errors:

```
NHibernate.Cache.ReadWriteCache - An item was expired by the cache while it was locked (increase your cache timeout)
```

These lines are followed by random entities that are supposed to be persisted to DB. Occasionally, these seem to fail to persist, or lack certain fields that should have been set, giving us a major headache.

The weirdest thing is that we still see this if 2nd level cache is turned off, which surprises me. The server this is running on has 64 GB RAM and usage usually lies around the 55-60 GB mark, because this hosts multiple sites.

Why am I seeing this when 2nd level cache is supposed to be off? First level cache shouldn't expire like this, right? I have also tried to set CachePriority to never expire for certain entities, but they still show up in the logs.

What am I doing wrong? Am I misinformed?

Answer (score 2):

We were getting this same message for entities with Read/Write caching enabled but when no 2nd level cache provider was set in the configuration.

Setting a provider in NH config file was enough to get rid of that message, even if the query and 2nd level caching were disabled for that provider (use_second_level_cache = off, use_query_cache = off).

We use memcache and this is how our NH configuration file looks like when we don't want 2nd level caching but at the same time avoid the log message:

```
<property name="cache.provider_class">NHibernate.Caches.MemCache.MemCacheProvider,NHibernate.Caches.MemCache</property>
<property name="cache.use_second_level_cache">false</property>
<property name="cache.use_query_cache">false</property>
```